# How to redirect to custom module after order is placed on admin panel?

Tags: magento-1.8, event-observer, module, sales-order

After I create an order (fill the form) in the admin panel and clicking **submit order** button, usually the page gets redirected to `order_view` page.

I use `sales_order_place_after` event , I need to redirect to a custom module grid page.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to override the method `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController::saveAction` and replace

```
$this->_redirect('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
```

with your desired url.

I don't think that using an event will help you in this case because you need to know if the order was actually created successfully.